# No enclosing instance of the type XXXXX is accessible in scopeJava(16777238)

Tags: java

If anyone could help me understand why my code is not working, I would greatly appreciate it! I'm relatively new to Java so please expect some noobish mistakes. Also, if it is necessary to help me with this question, I can post the other files of my code here as well. Thank you.

1. package Model;

   ```
   import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
   import javax.swing.JButton;
   import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

   import Controller.WordGuess;
   import Controller.Dictionary;

   class Observer implements ActionListener 
   {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent paramActionEvent)
       {
           JButton jButton = (JButton)paramActionEvent.getSource();

           if(jButton == WordGuess.this.newGameButton)
           {
               for(JButton jButton1 : WordGuess.this.keys)
               {
                   jButton1.setEnabled(true);
               }

               String str1 = Dictonary.getWord();
               WordGuess.this.gameKey.setText(str1);
               String str2 = "";

               for(int b = 0; b < str1.length(); b++)
               {
                   str2 = str2 + ".";
               }

               WordGuess.this.progressStatus.setText(str2);
               WordGuess.this.lifeCount = 5;
               WordGuess.this.status = 0;
               WordGuess.this.gameOver = false;
           } else {
               jButton.setEnabled(false);
               char c = jButton.getText().charAt(0);
               char[] arrayofChar = WordGuess.this.progressStatus.getText().toCharArray();
               String str = WordGuess.this.gameKey.getText();
               boolean bool = false;

               for(int b = 0; b < str.length(); b++)
               {
                   if (c == str.charAt(b))
                   {
                       arrayofChar[b] = c;
                       bool = true;
                   }
               }

               if (bool) {
                   WordGuess.this.progressStatus.setText(new String(arrayofChar));

                   if(!WordGuess.this.progressStatus.getText().contains("."))
                   {
                       WordGuess.this.status = 1;
                       WordGuess.this.gameOver = true;
                   }
               } else {
                   WordGuess.this.lifeCount--;

                   if(WordGuess.this.lifeCount == 0)
                   {
                       WordGuess.this.status = 2;
                       WordGuess.this.gameOver = true;
                   }
               }
           }

           WordGuess.this.repaint();

       }
   }
   ```

Comment: What do you think `WordGuess.this` references?

Comment: Also, please show the exact error message you are getting in your question.